# how to create a loop that shows how many questions remaining to be answered?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to transform this code into a loop:

```
var questions = 3;
var questionsLeft = '[ ' + questions + ' questions left]';
var question1 = prompt('Whats your name? ' + questionsLeft);
questions -= 1;
var questionsLeft = '[ ' + questions + ' questions left]';
var question2 = prompt('Whats your age? ' + questionsLeft);
questions -=1
var questionsLeft = '[ ' + questions + ' questions left]';
var question3 = prompt('Whats your dogs name? ' + questionsLeft);
```

So, i did this:

```
var question1;
var question2;
var question3;
var questions = 3;

for(var i = 0; i < questions; --questions) {
    var questionsLeft = '[' + questions + ' questions left]';

    if (questions == 3) {
        question1 = prompt('Whats your name? ' + questionsLeft);
    } 
    if (questions == 2) {
        question2 = prompt('Whats your age ' + questionsLeft);
    }
    if (questions == 1) {
        question2 = prompt('Whats your dog\'s name? '  + questionsLeft);
    }
}
```

I think this is the wrong way, right? How can i make it right?

---

UPDATE:

```
var question = ['Whats your name? ', 'Whats your age?', 'Whats your color?'];
var questions = 3;

for(var i = 0; i < questions; i++) {
        var questionsLeft = ' [' + questions + ' questions left]';
        alert(question[i] + questionsLeft);
}
```

Now its returning:

Whats your name? [3 question left]
Whats your age? [2 question left]
STOP

Comment: I'm breaking my head to do that..

Comment: When you have variables with numbers like that, you want an array instead.

Comment: but where i will store the answers?

Comment: it will prompting 
whats ur name [1 question left]
whats ur age [2 question left]
whats ur dog name [3 question left]

???

Comment: nop,  [3 question left] whats ur age [2 question left] whats ur dog name [1 question left] @maq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use an array like:

```
questions=["Whats your name?","Whats you age?","Whats your dog\'s name?"];
answers=[]
for (i=0; i<questions.length; i++) {
       var j=3-i;
       var questionsLeft = '[' + j + ' questions left]';
       answers.push(prompt(questions[i] + " "+ questionsLeft));
}
```

And you got all answers in `answers` array.

Answer (score 0):

you could also create an object

```
function Question(question) { 
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = "";
    this.answered = function() { return this.answer.length > 0; }
}
var questions = [];
questions.push(new Question("Question 1...");
questions.push(new Question("Question 2...");

function getNumberQuestionsLeft() { 
   var questionsLeft = [];
   for(var o in questions) { 
   var question = questions[o];
      if(!question.answered()) {
        questionsLeft.push(question); 
      }
   }
   return questionsLeft.length;
}


// using jQuery 
var questionsLeft = $.grep( questions, function(question ) {
    return !question.answered();
});
```